# Why are my Azure ML Flow API calls not authorized on some machines, even though the credentials are the same?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli, mlflow

I am using an Azure model registry. To access models from it, I'm using the Azure ML Flow library. The API call in question is in the function `mlflow.artifacts.download_artifacts()`. To authenticate, I've been using the Azure CLI. Inside of scripts, I use `os.system(az login -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD)`. This is all part of a docker container.

When I run docker build or docker compose on my laptop, this works great. It authenticates as the correct user, downloads the model, and has no issues. When I switch over to an Azure Workspace compute, it breaks. Both in docker build and docker compose, the login command runs, it prints out the information showing the correct user is logged in, and then throws an error on the `mlflow.artifacts.download_artifacts()` call. It's a 403 Not Authorized error.

My suspicion is that this has something to do with where Azure persistent login tokens are stored. On my laptop, which is running WSL, the tokens are stored on my windows file system under my user. However, the workstation only has the root user. The tokens are still stored in the proper `msal_token_cache.json` file, however this file is just in the `~/.azure` folder. In addition, when I manually take a working token from my laptop and put it into the token file on the workstation, it doesn't get used. In fact, when digging into the API call, on my laptop the token passed is the proper one from the token file, but on the workstation the token passed isn't in the token file at all. I'm honestly not sure where it's stored, but all this complexity has me thinking the issue is here.

Any advice for making this approach work or superior approaches to achieve the same end goal would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In case anyone else has the same issue, it ended up being an old managed identity on the workstation that the cli was trying to use